# Axios catch error from Response JSON is undefined

Tags: javascript, php, json, axios

I am returning a custom response from my PHP code and I don't know how I can use those responses for my page. I'm trying to use console.log to see the status and `msg` but I've had no luck.

Here is the PHP code:

```
if ($message->send()){
    return response()->json([
      'status' => 'success',
         'msg' => 'Message send =)'
   ],201);
}else{
    return response()->json([
      'status' => 'error',
         'msg' => 'Message did not send =('
   ],422);
}
```

And here is the JavaScript code:

```
 axios.post('url',params)
    .then(function(){
          console.log('send');
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        if (error.response){
            console.log(error.response.data.msg);
        }else if(error.request){
            console.log(error.response.data.msg)
        }else{
            console.log(error.response.data.msg);
        }
    });
```

I want to get the **status** and the **msg**
but the `console.log(error.response.data.msg)` is **undefined**.
Am I returning or using `console.log` on the wrong object?

I appreciate the help.

**I fixed it!**
I replaced the function(error) with function(response):

```
   .then(function(response){
          console.log('response.data.msg');
          console.log('response.data.status');
    })
    .catch(function(response){
          console.log('response.data.msg');
          console.log('response.data.status');
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried using `error.response.data.message` instead of msg?

Comment: Can't you debug your js code to see what does the `error` look like?

Comment: You should check your network, what data are you receiving from server then console.

Comment: @Carnageous i try that and i already fix my code. but i dont know why my post is negative. btw. Thanks.

Comment: @Kapcash Thanks! i debug my code and i replace the ERROR to RESPONSE. but my post is negative.

Answer (score 2):

Following the error response format, you need to use error.response.message to get the details of the error. At least, try to `console.log(error.response)` to know what's happening. Hope this help !